# Proper terminology for comparing decibels

Tags: acoustics, terminology

Decibels are a log-scale rather than linear unit, so for example 10 dB + 10 dB is about 13 dB, *not* 20dB. What then would be the proper terminology for comparing decibels?

For example, how would we describe the relationship between 13 dB and 10 dB? Would we say that "13 dB is 3 dB louder than 10 dB", or that "13 dB is 10 dB louder than 10 dB?" Is going from 10 dB to 13 dB "an increase of 3 dB" or "an increase of 10 dB"?

Or, to avoid confusion, is it better to completely avoid comparing decibels in terms normally associated with addition and subtraction, and always describe in terms of scale ("twice as loud", "half as loud", "300% louder", etc)?

Comment: 10 dB + 10 dB is 20 dB. This doesn't mean that you get a 20 dB gain by adding the outputs of two 10 dB amplifiers. It means that if you cascade two 10-dB amplifiers you get (ideally) 20 dB gain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by The Photon in the comments, you add decibels according to normal arithmetic, so 10 dB + 10 dB = 20 dB.  However, you need to be careful with what that means.  Saying that 13 dB is 3 dB louder than 10 dB signifies that the pressure amplitude of the 13 dB signal is roughly twice that of the 10 dB signal.

There is a reason for this usage, confusing as it may seem.  Human perception of loudness is roughly logarithmic, so increasing the signal by 3 dB sounds like (again, only roughly) the same increase in loudness regardless of what the initial level was.  (More precise measures of loudness exist, such as the [phon, described here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phon).)  From a human perception standpoint, saying that the signal increased in amplitude by, say, 50 mPa really doesn't tell you very much.  On the other hand, if you want to work on the physics of sound, human perception is somewhat irrelevant, and it is usually best to just work in units of pressure directly.

Comment: Thanks. When I wrote "10dB + 10dB = 13dB", I was thinking of combining signals (e.g. through constructive interference) - adding the _powers_ together. However, "10dB + 10dB = 13dB" is not the right way to represent adding the powers together, which is why I was confusing myself on terminology. Thanks!